# incorrect size of vector when converting Mat to Vector

Tags: opencv

I'm trying to convert the result Mat of templateMatch with the following code (which was found at: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26681713/convert-mat-to-array-vector-in-opencv)):

```
void convertmatVec(const cv::Mat& m, std::vector<uchar>& v) {
    if (m.isContinuous()) {
        v.assign(m.datastart, m.dataend);
    }
    else {
        printf("failed to convert / not continuous");           
        return;
    }
}
```

and when I check the size of the output it's not the same as the product of result's columns and rows (which is the same when I try to convert another Mat that I created):
result:
[image: result]

another Mat created with:

```
cv::Mat test(result.size(),false);
test.setTo(cv::Scalar(255));
```

which is then converted shows that the size is the same as the product:

[image: test]

So my question is how can I get the result's data so I can process it futher because I'm assuming the size of the vector should be the same as the product which it clearly isn't.

**EDIT1**: Added templateMatching code

```
void matchTemplatenoRotation(cv::Mat src, cv::Mat templ) {
cv::Mat img_display, result;

src.copyTo(img_display);

int result_cols = src.cols - templ.cols + 1;
int result_rows = src.rows - templ.rows + 1;

result.create(result_rows, result_cols, CV_32FC1);

cv::matchTemplate(src, templ, result, CV_TM_SQDIFF_NORMED);
cv::normalize(result, result, 0, 1, cv::NORM_MINMAX, -1, cv::Mat());
cv::Point minLoc, maxLoc;
double minVal, maxVal;

cv::minMaxLoc(result, &minVal, &maxVal, &minLoc, &maxLoc, cv::Mat());
cv::Point matchLoc = minLoc;

//end of templatematching
```

**EDIT2** follow up question:

How come when I create another Mat with following code:

```
cv::Mat test(cv::Size(result.cols, result.rows),true);
test.setTo(cv::Scalar(255));
//cv::imshow("test3", test);
std::vector<float> testVector;
convertmatVec(test, testVector);
```

the vector size is as following:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 4 times the expected number of elements in your vector because your matrix is of type `CV_32FC1`. If you look at the type of `m.datastart` and `m.dataend` you will see that they are `uchar*` and not `float*` as you expect.

To correct this, change `v.assign(m.datastart, m.dataend);` to `v.assign((float*)m.datastart, (float*)m.dataend);`. And you will need to pass a vector of float instead of a `vector<uchar>`.

Of course, your conversion function will only work for float type matrices. you could add some tests to detect the type of the matrix inside the function.

To answer your follow up question, it appears that you have the inverse problem. You are passing a `CV_8U` type matrix to a function that expects a `CV_32F` type one. Use your old conversion function for 8-bit matrices and use the fix I suggested for 32-bit floating-values matrices.  You can also add a test inside the conversion function to automatically choose the right conversion. I also advise you to read a bit on [OpenCV Mat class](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat) to understand better what type of data is in your matrices.

Comment: yup that fixed my problem. Thanks!

Comment: @Rok  Take a look at my edited answer for your follow-up question

Comment: I'll have to try that tomorrow as I'm not in the office anymore but thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

<del>It looks like your `const cv::Mat& m` has four channels.</del>

Another thing to consider: if this `Mat` is the result of a `matchTemplate()`, then you should be using a `vector<float>`, instead of `vector<uchar>`.

Comment: the initial Mats that are loaded images are loaded in as grayscale images though

also the result has only one channel

Comment: @Rok do you mind to add the piece of code the generates this `Mat`? That is an important code for properly answering your question.

Comment: the Mat that loads the image or the Mat that generates the test?

Comment: @Rok the one with problem

Comment: @Rok as I said, you should be using a `vector<float>`.