# Crop image with OpenCV\C++

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm using OpenCV (v 2.4.9.1, Ubuntu 16.04) to do a resize and crop on an image, the original image is a JPEG file with dimensions 640x480.

```
cv::Mat _aspect_preserving_resize(const cv::Mat& image, int target_width)
{
    cv::Mat output;
    int min_dim = ( image.cols >= image.rows ) ? image.rows : image.cols;
    float scale = ( ( float ) target_width ) / min_dim;
    cv::resize( image, output, cv::Size(int(image.cols*scale), int(image.rows*scale)));
    return output;
}

cv::Mat _center_crop(cv::Mat& image, cv::Size& input_size) 
{
    cv::Rect myROI(int(image.cols/2-input_size.width/2), int(image.rows/2-input_size.height/2), input_size.width, input_size.height);
    cv::Mat croppedImage = image(myROI);
    return croppedImage;
}

int min_input_size = int(input_size.height * 1.14);
cv::Mat image = cv::imread("power-dril/47105738371_72f83eeb37_z.jpg");
cv::Mat output = _aspect_preserving_resize(image, min_input_size);
cv::Mat result = _center_crop(output, input_size);
```

After this I display the images, and it looks perfect - as I would expect it to be:

[image]

The problem comes when I stream this image, where I notice that the size (in elements) of the cropped image is only a third of what I would expect. It looks as if there is only one cannel on the resultant crop. It should have had `224*224*3=150528`, but I'm getting only `50176` when I'm doing

```
std::cout << cropped_image.total() << " " << cropped_image.type() << endl;
>>> 50176 16
```

Any idea what's wrong here? The type of the resulting `cv::Mat` looks okay, and also visually it looks ok, so how there is only one channel?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[Basic Structures — OpenCV 2.4.13.7 documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-total) says:

> Mat::total
>
> Returns the total number of array elements.
>
> C++: size_t Mat::total() const
>
> The method returns the number of array elements (a number of pixels if
> the array represents an image).

Therefore, the return value is the number of pixels `224*224=50176` and your expected value is wrong.

Comment: Thanks @MikeCAT, when I print the the ```total()``` before cropping I do get the value that I expect. Is there a way to save\keep\retain the data cahnnel-wise?
EDIT: When I call ```channels()``` I do get ```3```.

Answer (score 0):

My terminology was wrong, as pointed by @MikeCAT, and it seems that the issue should be solved in the serialization logic. I went with a solution along the lines of this one:
[Convert Mat to Array/Vector in OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26681713/convert-mat-to-array-vector-in-opencv)

My original code didn't check the `channels()` function.

```
if (curr_img.isContinuous()) {
    int totalsz = curr_img.dataend-curr_img.datastart;
    array.assign(curr_img.datastart, curr_img.datastart + totalsz);
} else {
    int rowsz = CV_ELEM_SIZE(curr_img.type()) * curr_img.cols;
    for (int i = 0; i < curr_img.rows; ++i) {
        array.insert(array.end(), curr_img.ptr<uint8_t>(i), curr_img.ptr<uint8_t>(i) + rowsz);
    }
}
```