# What are my options to convert OpenCV reduce loop to a native iOS code. SIMD anyone?

Tags: ios, swift, opencv, simd

Which native iOS framework is best used to eradicate this cpu hog written in OpenCV?

```
/// Reduce the channel elements of given Mat to a single channel
static func reduce(input: Mat) throws -> Mat {
    
    let output = Mat(rows: input.rows(), cols: input.cols(), type: CvType.CV_8UC1)
    
    for x in 0 ..< input.rows() {
        for y in 0 ..< input.cols() {
            let value = input.get(row: x, col: y)
            let dataValue = value.reduce(0, +)
            try output.put(row: x, col: y, data: [dataValue])
        }
    }
    
    return output
}
```

takes about 20+ seconds to do those gets and puts on real world data I put this code through.

Comment: What's the type of `value`? If you can get a contiguous buffer of `Float` or `Double`, you can use the Accelerate framework (e.g. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/vdsp/3241136-sum) to sum it really fast

Comment: in the case I debugged it was an array of two double elements, thanks, will see if I can use Accelerate.

Comment: An array as in `Swift.Array`, or some other kind? Ultimately you just need one of the types that conforms to https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/acceleratebuffer

Comment: (lldb) p value
([Double]) $R1 = 2 values {
  [0] = 0
  [1] = 0
}

Comment: How can I tell from that output? po value is not a whole lot more helpful than this

Comment: `[Double]` is the sugared name for for a `Array<Double>`, so you're set. You can just do `let dataValue = vDSP.sum(value)`. Although if those arrays are small, it won't help much and you might need to think of other approaches. On an semi-related note, `value` and `dataValue` are oustandingly useless variable names. There isn't a single nameable thing in a computer system that _isn't_ fundamentally just a "value" or "data". Perhaps `let sum = vDSP.sum(array)` would be better? (though even `array` is a bad name. what are those values, exactly?)

Comment: r g b components of a pixel probably, this is someone else's code I'm taking over. The time hog is the get and put, not sure how to get rid of that and do pointer math in swift. The cowardly way would be to do this in objc flattening Mat if it's not flat https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26681713/convert-mat-to-array-vector-in-opencv I don't know how to dodge get and put in swift

Comment: Open CV Mat continuity explanation link from the link above https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/1972256

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248226/discussion-between-anton-tropashko-and-alexander).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your input matrix is `CV_64FC2`, call `computeSumX2` C function for each row.

Untested.

```
#include <arm_neon.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>

// Load 8 FP64 values, add pairwise, narrow uint64 to uint32, combine into a single vector
inline uint32x4_t reduce4( const double* rsi )
{
    // Load 8 values
    float64x2x4_t f64 = vld1q_f64_x4( rsi );
    // Add them pairwise
    float64x2_t f64_1 = vpaddq_f64( f64.val[ 0 ], f64.val[ 1 ] );
    float64x2_t f64_2 = vpaddq_f64( f64.val[ 2 ], f64.val[ 3 ] );

    // Convert FP64 to uint64
    uint64x2_t i64_1 = vcvtq_u64_f64( f64_1 );
    uint64x2_t i64_2 = vcvtq_u64_f64( f64_2 );

    // Convert int64 to int32 in a single vector, using saturation
    uint32x2_t low = vqmovn_u64( i64_1 );
    return vqmovn_high_u64( low, i64_2 );
}

// Compute pairwise sum of FP64 values, cast to bytes
void computeSumX2( uint8_t* rdi, size_t length, const double* rsi )
{
    const double* const rsiEnd = rsi + length * 2;
    size_t lengthAligned = ( length / 16 ) * 16;
    const double* const rsiEndAligned = rsi + lengthAligned * 2;

    for( ; rsi < rsiEndAligned; rsi += 16 * 2, rdi += 16 )
    {
        // Each iteration of the loop loads 32 source values, stores 16 bytes
        uint16x4_t low16 = vqmovn_u32( reduce4( rsi ) );
        uint16x8_t u16 = vqmovn_high_u32( low16, reduce4( rsi + 8 ) );
        uint8x8_t low8 = vqmovn_u16( u16 );

        low16 = vqmovn_u32( reduce4( rsi + 8 * 2 ) );
        u16 = vqmovn_high_u32( low16, reduce4( rsi + 8 * 3 ) );
        uint8x16_t res = vqmovn_high_u16( low8, u16 );

        vst1q_u8( rdi, res );
    }

    for( ; rsi < rsiEnd; rsi += 2, rdi++ )
    {
        // Each iteration of the loop loads 2 source values, stores a single byte
        float64x2_t f64 = vld1q_f64( rsi );
        double sum = vaddvq_f64( f64 );
        *rdi = (uint8_t)sum;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For folks such as myself who have a poor comprehension of ARM Intrinsics
a simpler solution is to bridge into Objective C code as Soonts did
and thusly ditch crude Swift api to opencv bypassing costly memory copying with gets and puts.

```
void fasterSumX2( const char *input,
                 int rows,
                 int columns,
                 long step,
                 int channels,
                 char* output,
                 long output_step
                 )
{
    for(int j = 0;j < rows;j++){
        for(int i = 0;i < columns;i++){
            long offset = step * j + i * channels;
            const unsigned char *ptr = (const unsigned char *)(input + offset);
            int res = ptr[0]+ptr[1];
            if (res > 0) {
                if (res > 255) {
                    assert(false);
                }
            }
            *(output + output_step * j + i) = res;
        }
    }
}
```