# Copy Vector of Contour Points into Mat

Tags: opencv, vector, point, mat

I am using OpenCV 3.1 with VS2012 C++/CLI.

I have stored the result of a finContours call into:

```
std::vector<std::vector<Point>> Contours;
```

Thus, Contours[0] is a vector of the contour points of the first contour.
Contours[1] is a vector of the contour points of the second vector, etc.

Now, I want to load one of the contours into a Mat  Based on [Convert Mat to vector <float> and Vector<float> to mat in opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20980723/convert-mat-to-vector-float-and-vectorfloat-to-mat-in-opencv) I thought something like this would work.

```
Mat testMat=Mat(Images->Contours[0].size(),2,CV_32FC1);    
memcpy(testMat.data,Images->Contours[0].data(),Images->Contours[0].size()*CV_32FC1);
```

I specified two columns because I each underlying pint must be composed of both an X point and a Y point and each of those should be a float.  However, when I access the Mat elements, I can see that the first element is not the underlying data but the total number of contour points.

Any help on the right way to accomplish this appreaciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with:

```
Mat testMat = Mat(Images->Contours[0]).reshape(1);
```

Now `testMat` is of type `CV_32SC1`, aka of `int`. If you need `float` you can:

```
testMat.convertTo(testMat, CV_32F);
```

---

Some more details and variants...

You can simply use the `Mat` constructor that accepts a `std::vector`:

```
vector<Point> v = { {0,1}, {2,3}, {4,5} };
Mat m(v);
```

With this, you get a 2 channel matrix with the underlying data in `v`. This means that if you change the value in `v`, also the values in `m` change.

```
v[0].x = 7; // also 'm' changes
```

If you want a *deep* copy of the values, so that changes in `v` are not reflected in `m`, you can use `clone`:

```
Mat m2 = Mat(v).clone();
```

Your matrices are of type `CV_32SC2`, i.e. 2 channels matrices of `int` (because `Point` uses `int`. Use `Point2f` for `float`). If you want a 2 columns single channel matrix you can use `reshape`:

```
Mat m3 = m2.reshape(1);
```

If you want to convert to `float` type, you need to use `convertTo`:

```
Mat m4;
m2.convertTo(m4, CV_32F);
```

Here some working code as a proof of concept:

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    vector<Point> v = { {0,1}, {2,3}, {4,5} };

    // changes in v affects m
    Mat m(v); 

    // changes in v doesn't affect m2
    Mat m2 = Mat(v).clone(); 

    // m is changed
    v[0].x = 7; 

    // m3 is a 2 columns single channel matrix
    Mat m3 = m2.reshape(1);

    // m4 is a matrix of floats
    Mat m4;
    m2.convertTo(m4, CV_32F);

    return 0;
}
```